# Sidekiq UploadedFile becomes Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, hash, sidekiq

What I am trying to do is use Sideqik to read some data from a file in the background. My problem is, when I pass the UploadedFile from my controller to the worker, it goes from being an UploadedFile to a Hash.

In my controller's create method:

```
file = params[file_key]                                                   
if not (file.nil? or file.class == ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)    
  raise "File not a file in Controller!"                                  
elsif not file.nil?                                                       
  ImporterWorker.perform_async(name, file)                                
end
```

The exception is not raised, and we merrily go on to ImporterWorker, which has:

```
def perform(name, file)                                                                                                    
  if not file.class == ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile                     
    raise "File is: #{ file.class }:#{ file.inspect }"             
  end
  ...
```

Where the exception IS raised, with "File is: Hash:" followed by a huge string of arbitrary things I imagine is the representation of the file contents, followed by "'original_filename' => 'Foo.xls'", and other such fields.

Why is it becoming a hash? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/The-Basics) :

> There's three ways to create a job in your application code
>   ...
>   All three ways create a Hash which represents the job, serializes that
>   Hash to a JSON string and pushes that String into a queue in Redis.
>   This means the arguments to your worker must be simple JSON datatypes
>   (numbers, strings, boolean, array, hash). Complex Ruby objects (e.g.
>   Date, Time, ActiveRecord instances) will not serialize properly.

So you need to store the file more permanently, and then pass a file path to the job for further processing